# CCAction in box2d world

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d, ccaction

i'm newbie to both cocos2d and box2d and i've been struggling for two days with this problem : i have a scene with many sprites dropping down (with bodies attached to them). and i have a BackgroundLayer from which i add my background image into the scene (which is not involded into the physics simulation). In my backgroundLayer i'm trying to perform an action on a sprite : 
(it blink in the first position and jump directly to the end position )

`id flyBubble = [CCEaseInOut actionWithAction:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:0.7 position:randomEndPosition]]`;

but my sprite doesn't respond at all to this action!! my sprite doesn't have any b2body attached and seems like it respond to the tick: method of the physics world (which is in my Main Scene). How can i perform an action to a sprite that doesn't have a b2body attached.
any help would be appreciated!!! thanks

here is the entire code :

```
    CCSprite *bubble = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"bubble.png"];
[self addChild:bubble];
CGPoint startPosition = ccp(100, 100);
bubble.position = startPosition;    
CGPoint endPosition = ccp(400, 400);

id flyBubble = [CCEaseInOut actionWithAction:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:0.7 position:randomEndPosition]];
id remove = [CCCallBlockN actionWithBlock:^(CCNode *node) {        
    [self removeFruit:(CCSprite *)node];        
}];

[bubble runAction:[CCSequence actions:flyBubble, remove, nil]];
```

Comment: where is your code of run action? smth like [sprite runAction: flyBubble]

Comment: i'm putting that code in the init method of the BackgroundLayer : [bubble runAction:[CCSequence actions:flyBubble, remove, nil]];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i did a little mistake that costs me lot of times. it was in this line of code

```
id flyBubble = [CCEaseInOut actionWithAction:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:0.7 position:randomEndPosition]];
```

CCEaseInOut doesn't work i don't know why!! when i used CCEaseExponentialInOut it worked perfectly.

Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I guess source and destination position of sprite is same. So no difference in action.

try like this..

```
sprite.position = ccp(0,0);

id flyBubble = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:0.7 position:randomEndPosition];

[sprite runAction:flyBubble];
```

Comment: i did fix the start position, i will edit the post with the entire code

Comment: and when i run this, it shows me the sprite in the startPosition during 1/60 seconds (which is the rate of my update method) and then jumps to the final position!!

Comment: if jump action(elastic movement) is not required then just use moveTo .

Comment: maybe i didn't make myself clear..actually, when i say jump that's mean that there are no action been performed. when i run, the sprite is in the start point then at end point, there is no animation (it's not showing the frames between the two points) blink start point-> blink end point no animation at all!!